# Example of Open sets in Projective Plane

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

In my self-study of Algebraic geometry, I came across the following argument;

> The Projective plane $\mathbb{P}^2$ comes with a standard Affine cover consisting of the three open subsets;
> $\mathcal{U}_j = \{ [z_0 : z_1 : z_2] : z_j \neq 0 \} $ for j = 0, 1, 2.

I wanted to play with this statement with a concrete example of the open subset and Here is how I tried to concretise the form for j = 0;
$\mathcal{U}_0 = \{ [1 : 0 : 0] , [1 : 1 : 0] , [1 : 0 : 1] , [1 : 1 : 1] \}$.

Could someone correct me if I'm mistaken?

Comment: Note that the $z_i$ could be any complex number (assuming you work over $\mathbb C$), not just $0$ or $1$!  So the set $\mathcal U_0$ is in fact infinite

Comment: @red_trumpet, oh! Thank you for mentioning it! I forgot to specify the underlying field! Yes, we're on $\mathbb{C}$!
Oh, so, can I say that my $\mathcal{U}_0$ of mine was just consisting of a set of bases to span an open set, right?
** I understood that the Projective basis needs a unit point so my example isn't a projective basis.

Comment: I mean the homogeneous coorrdinate, say, $[1: 0: 0]$ is a set of coordinates that is multiple ($\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$) of $[1, 0, 0]$, which includes the complex numbers.

Comment: Your $\mathcal U_0$ appears to be four points? That won't be open.

Comment: The open sets will be defined in terms of homogeneous polynomials of three variables. The projective plane can be seen as the quotient topology $X/\sim$ where $X=\mathbb A^3\setminus \{0\}$ and $x\sim y$ if they are scalar multiples of each other. Then the topology in the quotient is the largest topology which makes the quotient map $X\to X/\sim$ continuous. This gives  open sets of $X$ that contain $\lambda v$ when it contains $v$ and $\lambda\neq 0.$ This means the complement in $\mathbb A^n$ is closed and has the same property, hence is the set of roots to homogeneous polynomials.

Comment: Do you have an intuition about, say, the real projective plane?

Answer (score 1):

Here is (in my view) the correct way to understand open sets of $\Bbb{P}^2$ (or more generally $\Bbb{P}^n$ with appropriate modification). Don't forget what $\Bbb{P}^2$ *is*. It is a moduli space of lines in $\Bbb{A}^3$ passing through the origin. This is a fancy way of saying that it is the set of lines in $\Bbb{A}^3$ through the origin equipped with a topology and a variety structure (i.e. sheaf of rings). So, picture $\Bbb{A}^3$ as the $3$-space that we live in and consider that this space comes equipped with $3$ coordinate planes: $x=0, y=0,z=0$.

Now, the open sets in $\Bbb{P}^2$ that you are considering are defined by incidence relations. Namely, a line $\ell \in \Bbb{P}^2$ is in $\mathcal{U}_0$ if and only if for any nonzero $p\in \ell \subset \Bbb{A}^3$, we have $x(p)\ne 0$. That is to say, $\ell \in \mathcal{U}_0$ if and only if $\ell$ is not contained in the plane $x\ne 0$. Similarly, $\ell \in \mathcal{U}_1$ if and only if $\ell$ is not contained in the plane $y=0$, and finally, $\ell \in \mathcal{U}_2$ if and only if $\ell$ is
not contained in the plane $z=0$.

Since no line in $\Bbb{A}^3$ through the origin is contained in all three coordinate planes, the $\mathcal{U}_i$ form a cover. Moreover, since a "generic" line is not contained in a given plane, the condition of being in $\mathcal{U}_i$ is open. This is intuitively why the cover is open.